# Python Plot two subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a set of 12 plots that I want to save as one. The first set is a 3x3 subplot of 9 segments and the 2nd part is a 2x2 subplot of 4 segments. 
I've tried to add a subplot(121) between these two and I have tried to use figure(1) and figure(2), but both don't met me save the two images as one big image. Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
plt.subplot(331)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg1),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(332)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg2),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(333)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg3),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(334)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg4),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(335)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg5),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(336)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg6),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(337)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg7),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(338)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg8),origin="lower")
plt.subplot(339)
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg9),origin="lower")


plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(h1,origin="lower")
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(h2,origin="lower")
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(getpoly(h2),origin="lower")
plt.colorbar()  
plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(h1-getpoly(h2),origin="lower")
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: 3x3 + 2x2 = 9 + 4 = 13, how would you have 12 subplots then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to use `gridspec` with `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` as shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-using-subplotspec).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=gs[0])
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2, subplot_spec=gs[1])

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(9):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[i//3, i%3])
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(4,4))
    ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

for i in range(4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[i//2, i%2])
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(4,4))
    ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: One more question, I have colorbars in the right four images and the two most right images overlap with the colorbar of the left ones. Is there any way to fix that spacing easily?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I think you understand that the comments section is not meant to ask a new question. You have two options: 1. Edit your question to include the code you have problems with and an image of the undesired output, or, 2. Ask a new question about it.